# MsChart Add Multiple Series from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I want to add different line chart one at the time to my chart. So i have a textbox with a button . i input a code and load the series from my database. The problem is that the new line series override the old line series. so i decided to keep tract of the added series into a gridview, i loop through it and fill the chart; same result.

This is my code

```
void AddSerie(string stockName)
    {
        try
        {

            Legend legend = new Legend(stockName);
            Chart1.Legends.Add(legend);
            Series series = new Series(stockName);
            Chart1.Series.Add(series);

             string[] _data = new string[3];
            _data[0] = stockName;
            _data[1] = "2010-01-01";
            _data[2] = "2015-03-15";

            DataSet ds = DBSelect(_data, "web_price_series");

            Chart1.DataSource = ds;
            Chart1.Series[stockName].XValueMember = "tdate";
            Chart1.Series[stockName].YValueMembers = "value";
            Chart1.Series[stockName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            Chart1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

this is how i call the method

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                AddSerie(row.Cells[0].Text);
            }
        }
```

and i have the legend showing two series but the chart displays only one line.

[image]

i added this picture to show the second output of the chart for two companies using MarkerStyle.

[image]

This is an example of what i want to achieve .

[image]

This is the structure of the table

[image]

any help?

Comment: At the first glance I'd say this should work. Can you confirm the Y-values in the blue series' points? (Hint: Use the debugger!)

Comment: @Taw yes i confirm the Y-values . It seems the chart does not keep the previous line series into memory before drawing the new one.

Comment: Please also have a look at the chart's data fields, read at `Chart1.Series[0].Points[...].YValues[0];`. I should say though, that I noticed the ASP tag only now and that I'm not familiar with ASP and its Charts, only Winforms. But I would expect them to be very similar. - Btw: `AddSerie(row.Cells[0].Text);` is this a typo or a function? (I would expect the method to be called `AddSeries`..)

Comment: Also, looking at the dates: The two series will only both be visible where the date X-data actually overlap. If Min and max are set so that they don't only the one in the data wndow is visible. The Graph goes from 2010-2013, the (blue?) dates go from 2014-2015.

Comment: @Taw AddSerie() it is a method that perfoms the drawing of the chart. It is defined at the top of the post. i just call that method to show a chart for a given  company code.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. (Not quite awake ;-) and there you pull data 2010-2015 from the DB for all/both series.

Comment: @TaW yea , i passes a range date and it affects both series. after fetching data for the first serie , the same parameter are used for the second series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73224/discussion-between-taw-and-jmocke).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the databind i used another method: 
**Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XValues, Yalues);**

```
void AddSerie(string stockName)
{
    try
    {

        Legend legend = new Legend(stockName);
        Chart1.Legends.Add(legend);
        Series series = new Series(stockName);
        Chart1.Series.Add(series);

         string[] _data = new string[3];
        _data[0] = stockName;
        _data[1] = "2010-01-01";
        _data[2] = "2015-03-15";

        DataSet ds = DBSelect(_data, "web_price_series");

        Chart1.DataSource = ds;
        Chart1.Series[stockName].XValueMember = "tdate";
        Chart1.Series[stockName].YValueMembers = "value";
        Chart1.Series[stockName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
           Chart1.Series[stockName].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[1]);
        }

       // Chart1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```