# Combine charts in c#

Tags: c#, plot, graph, charts

I'm outputting my data in 3 excel sheets and generating 3 charts using the same in my c# code. These 3 charts are of 'line' type. What I want to do is combine these 3 in one chart. Is there any way to do this?
I'm new in c# coding and since last week I tried a lot to find a way to do this. But I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: In the chart control, you have an option of adding multiple series. Here's another [stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098308/mschart-add-multiple-series-from-database) on the subject

Comment: Also: you can have more that one chartarea in one chart.

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one ChartArea. I've done it in order to have multiple Y-axes. Here's an eye-opening VS [project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) that demonstrate lots of ways to use Chart.